# How to add styles to images in a org file

Tags: html, image, border, org-mode

I am creating a manual in an org file which has images as well. I then export the org file to html file. I want to add border to images, so I tried following:

```
 #+ATTR_HTML: style="border:2px solid #ccc;"                                                                                                                                                                      
 [[./dashboardNew1.png]]
```

But this is not getting reflected in html. Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should correct the syntax for the attributes directive:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :style border:2px solid #ccc;
[[./dashboardNew1.png]]
```

The `style=""` syntax is deprecated, but there are still tutorials using this syntax. The [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-HTML-export.html#Images-in-HTML-export) is always up to date.